# WkHtmlToPDF libjpeg error on Elastic Beanstalk Instance

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having trouble getting  WkHtmlToPDF working on a Elastic Beanstalk instance for PHP.

When I try and create a PDF file I hit the following error:

> Severity: error --> Exception: The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
>   stderr: "/var/app/current/application/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I try and yum install libjpeg on the server it's already installed. From what I can tell this may be related to the following issue: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1822 ?

For reference, I am using https://packagist.org/packages/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 in composer.

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the older 0.11.0-RC1 version of wkhtmltopdf instead of the current 0.12.2.1.

From what I can tell the forthcoming 0.12.13 should hopefully fix this issue as well.